# Tests are not started after db creation by liquibase

Tags: java, exit, dbunit, liquibase

I'm testing datasource layer using dbunit, junit, liquibase, hsqldb.
I'm using in memory-state of hsqldb. 
Each time I start test, I create db structure using liquibase via command line:

```
 @BeforeClass
 public static void setupDatabase() throws Exception
 {
    ...
    try{
        Main.main( new String[]{
            "--defaultsFile=db/properties/db.test.properties",
            "--logLevel=debug",
            "update"}
        );
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(  e );
    }
    System.out.println( "QQQQ" );
    ...
 }
```

In the output I can see, that sql scripts are executed successfully:

```
Connected to SA@jdbc:hsqldb:mem:datasourcedb
...
Successfully released change log lock

Liquibase Update Successful
```

But for some reason I can not see the output from `System.out.println`. I develop in IDEA. I see `Process finished with exit code 0.` in debug window, but at the same time I see that 
test has not been terminated. I suppose the first message is related to the "main" function.

Any Idea?

Comment: So the app just hangs and never exits?

Comment: I've updated my question. Some process exits with code 0, but test is not terminated and hangs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to hazard a wild guess, but if you're using `liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.main(String[])` to run your Liquibase update scripts then you shouldn't be—that method exits with `System.exit(0)`.

Instead, take a [look at this forum post](http://forum.liquibase.org/topic/running-updates-programmatically-using-junit) which describes how to run Liquibase updates programmatically, specifically for use in unit tests.